# Should Spring Boot Data JPA automatically create EntityManagerFactory bean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Should Spring Boot Data JPA automatically create EntityManagerFactory bean?

I have added a table using Liquibase called Fred to my code, and now I wish to add JPA support for this.

Upon adding:

```
public interface FredRepository extends JpaRepository<Fred, Long> {
}
```

I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

I understood that this bean should be created by spring. Can anyone explain when spring creates this bean for me? If it doesn't, why not?

SpringBoot TRACE logs containing EntityManager

```
o.s.b.a.condition.OnClassCondition       : Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerEntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor matched due to @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'
Configuration$BootstrapExecutorCondition : Condition JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer did not match due to AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition.LazyBootstrapMode @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy) did not find property 'bootstrap-mode'; NestedCondition on JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition.DeferredBootstrapMode @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=deferred) did not find property 'bootstrap-mode'
o.s.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults     : Found bean property 'entityManager' of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager]
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4ba89729: defining beans (shortened for brevity)
WARN 43335 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fredRepository' defined in org.xxx.jpa.FredRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#492d38a2' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#492d38a2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerEntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor:
      Did not match:
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)
   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer:
      Did not match:
         - AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition.LazyBootstrapMode @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy) did not find property 'bootstrap-mode'; NestedCondition on JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition.DeferredBootstrapMode @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=deferred) did not find property 'bootstrap-mode' (JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition)
```

Entity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Fred {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String integrationkey;
}
```

pom.xml (recently added spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>component</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>company :: component</name>
    <description>component</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <company.shared.lib.version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</company.shared.lib.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibaseVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.company.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>dto-model</artifactId>
            <version>${company.shared.lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.212</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

version numbers from parent

```
    <properties>
        <dropwizard.metrics.version>4.2.10</dropwizard.metrics.version>
        <activemq.version>5.17.1</activemq.version>
        <aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.version>2.0.1</aries.jax.rs.whiteboard.version>
        <aries.jpa.api.version>2.7.3</aries.jpa.api.version>
        <bsf.version>2.4.0</bsf.version>
        <eclipselink.version>2.5.1</eclipselink.version>
        <camel.version>3.15.0</camel.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.11.0</commons.io.version>
        <commons.lang.version>2.6</commons.lang.version>
        <cucumber.version>7.1.0</cucumber.version>
        <cxf.version>3.5.1</cxf.version>
        <dhcp4java.version>1.1.0</dhcp4java.version>
        <drools.version>7.31.0.Final</drools.version>
        <geohash.version>1.4.0</geohash.version>
        <glassfish.jaxb.version>2.3.2</glassfish.jaxb.version>
        <grpc.version>1.43.2</grpc.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.6</gson.version>
        <guava.version>31.0.1-jre</guava.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.1.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <httpcore.version>4.4.4</httpcore.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.13</httpclient.version>
        <ignite.version>2.14.0</ignite.version>
        <jackson.version>2.13.1</jackson.version>
        <jaeger.version>0.34.0</jaeger.version>
        <jakarta.annotation.version>1.3.5</jakarta.annotation.version>
        <jakarta.xml.version>2.3.3</jakarta.xml.version>
        <jakarta.mail.version>1.6.7</jakarta.mail.version>
        <javax.validation.version>2.0.1.Final</javax.validation.version>
        <jaxrs.version>2.1</jaxrs.version>
        <jboss-logging.version>3.4.1.Final</jboss-logging.version>
        <jcifs.version>2.1.6</jcifs.version>
        <jexl.version>2.1.1</jexl.version>
        <jicmp.version>3.0.0</jicmp.version>
        <jicmp6.version>2.0.1</jicmp6.version>
        <jna.version>4.4.0</jna.version>
        <joda.time.version>2.1</joda.time.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <jsonPatch.version>1.13</jsonPatch.version>
        <jacksonCoreUtils.version>2.0</jacksonCoreUtils.version>
        <fgeMsgSimple.version>1.2</fgeMsgSimple.version>
        <fgeBtf.version>1.3</fgeBtf.version>
        <json.version>20171018</json.version>
        <jsr250.version>1.0</jsr250.version>
        <jsr305.version>3.0.2</jsr305.version>
        <karaf.version>4.3.6</karaf.version>
        <keycloak.version>18.0.0</keycloak.version>
        <liquibaseVersion>4.17.0</liquibaseVersion>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <mina.version>2.1.5</mina.version>
        <netty3.version>3.10.6.Final</netty3.version>
        <netty4.version>4.1.78.Final</netty4.version>
        <xxx.tracker.version>0.7</xxx.tracker.version>
        <opentracing.version>0.31.0</opentracing.version>
        <org.osgi.service.jdbc.version>1.0.0</org.osgi.service.jdbc.version>
        <osgi.version>7.0.0</osgi.version>
        <pax.jdbc.version>1.5.2</pax.jdbc.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.5.0</postgresql.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.4</testcontainers.version>
        <prometheus.version>0.16.0</prometheus.version>
        <protobuf.version>3.17.3</protobuf.version>   <!-- WARNING: this also controls the version of the protobuf compiler, change at your risk!-->
        <rate.limitted.logger.version>2.0.2</rate.limitted.logger.version>
        <rest-assured.version>4.3.3</rest-assured.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.33</slf4j.version>
        <snmp4j.version>2.5.5</snmp4j.version>
        <snmp4j.agent.version>2.5.3</snmp4j.agent.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.23</spring.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.4</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.7.3</spring-security.version>
        <spring-kafka.version>2.8.6</spring-kafka.version>
        <swagger.version>2.1.1</swagger.version>
        <xxx.shared.lib.version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</xxx.shared.lib.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.16.3</testcontainers.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <lombok.binding.version>0.2.0</lombok.binding.version>
        <mockito.version>4.8.0</mockito.version>
        <jupiter.version>5.9.0</jupiter.version>
        <jib.version>3.2.1</jib.version>
        <surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire.version>
        <failsafe.version>3.0.0-M5</failsafe.version>
    </properties>
```

stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fredRepository' defined in org.xxx.jpa.FredRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4c57ca10' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4c57ca10': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4c57ca10': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 99 more
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xxx

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/xxx
    username: xxx
    password: xxx

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate

  liquibase:
    change-log: db/changelog/changelog.xml
```

Comment: Did you tried manually defining `spring.jpa.database-platform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was missing the hibernate jars in my pom.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also worth pointing out that hibernate 6 requires spring boot 3 and doesn't work with spring boot 2.

Answer (score 1):

In the properties file you provide, datasource is configured for Postgres, but according to pom file, H2 should be configured during tests (the Postgres driver and url should be in `src/main/resources/application.yaml` only).

Maybe, you just need to override datasource properties in **test resources** (`src/test/resources/application.yaml`):

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
    url=jdbc:h2:mem:sample;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username=sa
    password=password
```

#### Side note

[Keycloak adapters for Spring are very deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Do not use it.

See [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for alternatives to configure resource-servers.

For consuming admin API, just use one of Spring REST clients (`@FeignClient`, `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`)

Comment: Side note was useful